# How to numpy sum take range repeat

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

How to numpy sum take range repeatedly?
For example from below array.

```
array([[1,2],
       [3,4],
       [5,6],
       [7,8],
       ...
       [i,j]])
```

I would like to below after sum take two from column 1 and mean take two from column 2 repeatedly.
[4,3] = [sum(1,3), mean(2,4)]...

```
array([[4,3],
       [12,7],
       ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a trick to do your job:

```
b = np.zeros((int(a.shape[0]/2), *a.shape[1:]))
b[:, 0] = np.sum(a.reshape(-1, 2, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0]
b[:, 1] = np.mean(a.reshape(-1, 2, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, 2)[:, 1]
```

Which basically reshapes to chunk data into every two rows with `a.reshape(-1, 2, 2)`, then do any calculations you would like, and finally reshape it back to original shape by `reshape(-1, 2)`. You can probably optimize it if efficiency matters for you by removing extra column calculations of num/mean.

EDIT: You can convert your datatype to int if that is a requirement:

```
b = b.astype(int)
```

output for array:

```
[[ 1  2]
 [ 3  4]
 [ 5  6]
 [ 7  8]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]]
```

is:

```
[[ 4  3]
 [12  7]
 [20 11]]
```

UPDATE:  In case of general range.
Range is number of rows you want to bundle together and this answer assumes number of rows in data is multiple of range. i.e. the array is broadcast able to shape(-1,3,2):

```
range = 3
b = np.zeros((int(a.shape[0]/range), *a.shape[1:]))
b[:, 0] = np.sum(a.reshape(-1, range, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0]
b[:, 1] = np.mean(a.reshape(-1, range, 2), axis=1).reshape(-1, 2)[:, 1]
```

Output for range 3:

```
[[ 9.  4.]
 [27. 10.]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, I got it when I ticked it is an answer. Yours able to scale.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```py
np.vstack((my_array[::2, 0] + my_array[1::2, 0], (my_array[::2, 1] + my_array[1::2, 1]) / 2)).T
```

It is all numpy indexing really. `my_array[::2, 0]` will be the array:

```py
[1, 5, ...]
```

while `my_array[1::2, 0]` is the array:

```py
[3, 7, ...]
```

Hence, you can add them to get the first column of your resulting array. Note that this results in an array with shape `(n, )`. You can do the same for computing the mean, but you have to change `0` by `1` to get the second column.

Once you get your two arrays, you can stack them vertically using `vstack`, and finally taking the transpose with the attribute `T` to get the right shape.

I'm not sure this is the more efficient way of doing this though.

Comment: Nice, I never knew you could do this sort of : : slice. Upvote.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know if there is way to set range. ex. sum(my_array[::2, 0], my_array[1::2, 0]) instead of my_array[::2, 0] + my_array[1::2, 0] in the vstack.

Comment: I did not understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: @tknv I updated my answer to include general range if it works for you.

Comment: Oh OK I understand thanks to @Ehsan! However, my answer doesn't scale as well as yours for this case unfortunately.